# What are the advantages of revving files with a hash over a version or date?

Tags: caching, hash, web, build

It's pretty common when building web sites/apps to add a revision marker to certain files during the build process to bust caching. For example, the files

`style.css`
`script.js`

might be renamed by a build script to

`58198123.style.css`
`87012174.script.js`

Usually applications use an MD5 hash of the file contents for revision markers (for example: Ant build script, Yeoman, Drupal). I'm wondering what are the benefits of using a hash over a version number, serial revision, or date string? Each of those adds a little human readable information to a file, which I find pleasant. I'm sure there are good reasons to do it the hash way, I just haven't seen any explicitly described.

Comment: If the file is modified, then the change undone, the hash will return to the previous value, and existing caches will be valid. File versions and dates do not have this property. Another nice property of hashes is that can be generated without committing, which is very handy when testing local changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with @Raymond Chen (comment to your question above) where hashes "revert" when changes "revert", and hashes can be generated without committing.

However, IMHO, the most significant reason for hashes over "version" or "date" is to avoid collisions, where multiple developers may be working, but do not share a "centralized-server" to coordinate revision-number-updates, or to resolve accidental-time-collisions.

For example:

- if two developers want to make a change at the *same-time*, updating a "timestamp" is ambiguous (but a hash is not).
- if two developers are working but do not share a central "version-number-server" (for example, one of them is "offline"), then updating the version number is ambiguous (because both would claim the next-version-number), but a hash is not ambiguous.

The "distributed" model is why git/mercurial moved to "hashes", to drop the need for a central version-number-server.

In your specific case, if you are the *only* developer, you could argue that you don't need this "reconcile-from-distributed-changes" feature.  However, version numbers become confusing/ambiguous when you fork/branch, then merge.

Subversion handles this by monotonically-incrementing a single number for the *whole* repository, but in your use case, you're talking about a version number upon each file.  Previous version control systems (like `cvs`, `rcs`, `sccs`, etc.) handled the version-number-on-each-file by "adding" a "counter" for each branch/merge.  These numbers became complex, and still enabled ambiguities.  For example, one file in the repository could have a version like `2.3.27`, and another could have `3.2` and another could have `26` at the *same-time*, and simultaneously each of those versions could be "valid" for a single file at different parts of the file's history on different branches (it got confusing).  For example, `2.4.12.37.2` got messy if a `MyFileA.txt` was branched/merged a lot, and it meant nothing if two files accidentally had the same version `26` (for one file, it was years ago before twenty branches/merges, and for another file, that's the current version).

Comment: Perfect explanation. I had completely missed the multiple developer point (which is odd because I use git and contribute to plenty of open source projects). <3 Stack Overflow.